# When a former employer or consultant installed a managed package which can't easily be identified, how can I get the package Id?

Tags: managed-package, deployment, appexchange, scratch-org, package-install

I've recently joined a company with several manage packages that are deeply integrated into our solution.

Before we can deploy any meaningful subset of metadata to a scratch org it is absolutely required that we install several of these packages.

However, searching the Appexchange for two of these packages has only ambiguous results.
Trying to install each of the candidates and then looking for the email to inform me of the success is inefficent.  Moreover, it is easy to guess wrong.

Is there any way to get the correct package Id from the production org?
Or to search the AppExchange by namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SFDX conveniently has a feature that does this.

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list -u org-name-or-alias
```

You can directly use the package Ids from the list to install the packages into other orgs. Note that you'll need the "password" if that version is password-protected, which may be a whole separate problem, but this will at least get you most of the way there.